# How to handle the onchange event on a select in c# mvc 4?

Tags: html, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, input

I was wondering if it's possible to handle an onchange event in c#. The situation is that i have a select which contains my datas:

```
<select id="choix_contact" onchange="javascript:RemplirTextbox();">
    <option>Choisir un contact</option>
    @if (ViewBag.ListeContacts != null)
    {
        foreach (var Contact in ViewBag.ListeContacts)
        {
            <option>@Contact.Nom</option>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <option>Pas de contact</option>  
    }  
</select>
```

So the idea is when i choose a contact in my select, i would like to fill textboxes with the other properties of the contact. Is it possible to access Html input in c# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can handle onChange event using javaScript, or some kind of library, like jQuery